# Is it possible to execute a bashscript after kill a terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh, kill-process

I know that have a file called `.bash_profile` that executes code (bashscript) when you open a terminal.

And there is another file that is called `.bash_logout` that executes code when you exit the terminal.

How I would execute some script when terminal is killed?

(`.bash_logout` do not cover this when terminal is killed).

Comment: You may check the trap command. In addition I think it will be better to post this question to https://serverfault.com/ to find a better answer...

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal is killed"? Neither `.bash_profile` nor `.bash_logout` have anything to do with the terminal: they are executed when a login shell starts and exits, respectively. The only way the terminal is involved is if it starts and stops the shell.

Comment: @chepner, terminal killed by vscode for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How I would execute some script when terminal is killed?

I interpret this as *"execute a script when the terminal window is closed"*. To do so, add the following inside your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
trap '[ -t 0 ] || command to execute' EXIT
```

Of course you can replace `command to execute` with `source ~/.bash_exit` and put all the commands inside the file `.bash_exit` in your home directory.

The special EXIT trap is executed  whenever the shell exits (e.g. by closing the terminal, but also by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on the prompt, or executing `exit`, or ...).

`[ -t 0 ]` checks whether stdin is connected to a terminal. Due to `||` the next command is executed only if that test fails, which it does when closing the terminal, but doesn't for other common ways to exit bash (e.g. pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on the prompt or executing `exit`).

#### Failed attempts (read only if you try to find and alternative)

In the terminals I have heard of, bash always receives a SIGHUP signal when the window is closed. Sometimes there are even two SIGHUPs; one from the terminal, and one from the kernel when the pty (pseudoterminal) is closed. However, sometimes both SIGHUPs are lost in interactive sessions, because bash's [readline temporarily uses its own traps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/491626/187122). Strangely enough, the SIGHUPs always seem to get caught when there is an EXIT trap; even if that EXIT trap does nothing.

However, I strongly advise against setting any trap on SIGHUP. Bash processes non-EXIT traps only after the current command finished. If you ran `sh -c 'while true; do true; done'` and closed the terminal, bash would continue to run in the background as if you had used `disown` or `nohup`.

Comment: This presupposes that the terminal sends a HUP signal to its children when you kill it. I'm not in a place where I can experiment, but this sounds like behavior which could depend on the terminal or perhaps the desktop environment or window manager, and thus it might make sense to mention where you have tested this.

Comment: I'm totally with you. I received my SIGHUP from gnome-terminal and checked some other questions/answers where the same signal was sent from lxterminal, xterm, and even tmux without any graphical interface (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/335374/187122) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/491626/187122))
. I haven't found any standard dictating that SIGHUP is sent, but since [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) defined  SIGHUP as the *"`signal sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed.`"* I just assumed this to be the de-facto standard.

Comment: Anyways, I found a way without using SIGHUP, which was very problematic for other reasons too.

Comment: @Socowi, vscode have a way to kill the terminal, unluckily it doesn't trigger the command you posted above. I don't if the environment counts, I'm using Windows and Git bash.

Comment: Yes, the terminal can make a difference, but the biggest problem is probably windows. Signals, traps, and TTYs are a Linux thing. Not sure how much of this works in git bash on windows. For the beginning you can try to remove the `[ -t 0 ] ||` part and see if that works.